# Haskell Exercise Mooc FI Do notation

Tags: haskell

This is the exercise from https://haskell.mooc.fi/ training

```
-- Ex 5: define the IO operation readUntil f, which reads lines from
-- the user and returns them as a list. Reading is stopped when f
-- returns True for a line. (The value for which f returns True is not
-- returned.)
--
-- Example in GHCi:
--   *Set11> readUntil (=="STOP")
--   bananas
--   garlic
--   pakchoi
--   STOP
--   ["bananas","garlic","pakchoi"]

readUntil :: (String -> Bool) -> IO [String]
readUntil f = todo
```

Would you be able to provide me a hint / solution using do notation ?
I am a beginning with the do notation and the "conditional logic" as well as looping is too complex for me at the  moment.

Thank you so much

Comment: If you have no idea how to start and the concepts involved are too complex for you at the moment, perhaps it woudl be better to do a different exercise for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only do-notation and conditional statements I found the following solution:

```
readUntil :: (String -> Bool) -> IO [String]          
readUntil f = do x <- getLine; 
                 if f x then (return []) else (do xs <- readUntil f
                                                  return (x : xs))
```

The function first reads one line with `getLine` from prelude and then checks whether `(f x)` is true. It then returns just the empty list. We can't just write `... if f x then [] ...` because `[]` has not the type `IO [String]` but just `[String]`. To make `[]` the type `IO [String]` we can use the function `return` or `pure` but with do-notation I use the `return` function, because it is included in the `Monad` typeclass.
If `f x` equals `False` we then use a second do-block to recursively call the function again and again until we get an Input for which `f x == True` and therefore returns the empty list. The do-notation is necessary because xs must have type `[String]`, but `readUntil` has the type `IO [String]`. We can't use the `:` ("cons") operator with object of type `IO String` and therefore can't generate the list we want. We then add x to the list xs of all our other inputs and return it.

For a more general version of the function `readUntil` which is able to work with any monad and not just the `IO` Monad, see the comment of Will Ness

Comment: Part of your definition seems to be missing; also, as a quibble, Haskell’s if-then-else construct doesn’t require parentheses around its subexpressions.

Comment: @jlwoodwa but having visual cues can help with code's readability.

Comment: it's more idiomatic to rename `k` to `xs` so as to have `x:xs` instead of `x:k`. also, `getLineUntil` might be a better name for that function, since it does `getLine` and doesn't do any `read`ing. then we can abstract the `getLine` away and have it as a parameter to `getUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> IO a -> IO [a]` or even `collectUntil :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]`

Comment: @WillNess yes, the xs would be a better name, I'll change that. I can't rename the function `readUntil`, because it is explicitly asked for a function of that name (`readUntil f = todo`) but I'll link your comment with my answer, that anyone who might need a more general version can look at your functions `collectUntil` and `getUntil`